# Error connecting to Informix using .NET driver

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, informix

I have a problem connecting to Informix server(windows) using ADO.NET. I'm using Listing 1 code from this article: 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0510durity/

Reported error is "ERROR [HY000] [Informix .NET provider][Informix]Invalid connection-type.". Error code is "-25539".

From the error reference:
"The connection-type is invalid for the database server. This message appears when the database server is configured to address specific connection requests, for example for an ER or HDR connection."

After further searching I found that this is related with connection security levels but I don't know how to fix this.

Also, Open Admin Tool successfully connected to server using same connection data used in .NET demo.

I'm running windows 7 64bit and this SDK version: clientsdk.3.50.FC9DE.WIN.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried connecting to Informix DRDA service with Informix .NET provider and that combination doesn't work. When I switched to SQLI service and added Protocol=olsoctcp to connection string everything worked fine. After that I found this article

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1007dsnetids/index.html

and switched to IBM Data Server .NET Provider because I needed to fetch database metadata and old Informix provider doesn't support fetching database metadata.